# Using a function over a vector or data frame

Tags: r, loops, apply, purrr

I just wrote a function (e.g., `func(a, x, y, z)`) x, y, and z are fixed parameters, and I have either a vector (`a <- seq(1, 14, 0.25)`) or a data frame for a. What would be the best way to apply the function to it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If your function is vectorised you can directly pass `a` to it.

For example,

```
func <- function(a, x, y, z) {
  a + x + y + z
}
a <- seq(1, 14, 0.25)
func(a, 2, 3, 4)

#[1] 10.00 10.25 10.50 10.75 11.00 11.25 11.50 11.75 12.00 12.25 12.50 12.75
#[13] 13.00 13.25 13.50 13.75 14.00 14.25 14.50 14.75 15.00 15.25 15.50 15.75
#[25] 16.00 16.25 16.50 16.75 17.00 17.25 17.50 17.75 18.00 18.25 18.50 18.75
#[37] 19.00 19.25 19.50 19.75 20.00 20.25 20.50 20.75 21.00 21.25 21.50 21.75
#[49] 22.00 22.25 22.50 22.75 23.00
```

If your function is not vectorised you need to use some sort of loop to pass each `a` value separately. With `sapply` -

```
sapply(a, function(x) func(x, 2, 3, 4))
```